# Is there a way to align nested children to my css grid?

Tags: vue.js, css-grid

I'm working with Laravel and Vue.js and I have a Application.vue which looks like this

```
<template>
  <div id="application-container" class="grid">
      <VueHeader></VueHeader>
      <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueHeader from '@/components/widgets/VueHeader';
export default {
    components:{VueHeader}
}
</script>

<style>
.grid{
    display:  grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    height: 100vh;
}
</style>
```

And a Game.vue which looks like this

```
<template>
    <div id="game-container">
        <div id="game-component-menu"></div>
        <div id="game-component-area">Game</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Game'
}
</script>

<style scoped>
#game-container{
    grid-column: 2 / 11;
    grid-row: 1 / 11;
}

#game-component-menu{
    grid-column: 1 / 11;
    grid-row: 2 / 11;
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
}

#game-component-area{
    grid-column: 1 / 11;
    grid-row: 3 / 11;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
</style>
```

The router view is displaying the Game component. The problem is that the game component need to have a div game-container to wrap the menu and the area because you can not have multiple divs in a template. That causes my grid to stop working for the child elements of game-container. How can I fix this without nesting more grids. I would like to use the grid from the Application.vue troughout my application.

Answer (score 0):

I would do following:

create a file and name is Fragment.js

```js
export default {
  functional: true,
  render(h, ctx) {
      return ctx.children;
  }
};
```

in you component, you can use it like below:

```js
<template>
    <Fragment>
        <div id="game-component-menu"></div>
        <div id="game-component-area">Game</div>
    </Fragment>
</template>
<script>
import Fragment from '../Fragment'; // update the path as per your directory structure.
</script>
```

Working example can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-neumann-mrm94)